# Unable to autoload constant SetTitle /controllers/concerns/set_title.rb to define it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am trying to set page title with concern. I have a set_title.rb file under my concerns folder.

```
module SetTitle
extend ActiveSupport::Concern

included do
    before_action:set_name
end

def set_name
    if current_user
        {
            @set_title_name = current_user.name
        }
    else
        {
            @set_title_name = "Guest"
        }
    end
end
```

And this is my application_controller.rb file

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
include DeviseWhitelist
include SetTitle
end
```

I don't get any errors when there is a only DeviseWhitelist but when i try to add more concerns than it throws an error.

Error message is :

> Unable to autoload constant SetTitle, expected /Users/User/Desktop/Rails/Account/app/controllers/concerns/set_title.rb to define it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the braces that i used under the IF/ELSE statement.
I removed them and problem is solved.